# Can I add an object after the verb "live"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, objects

I wrote the following sentence

> They lived a lot of good experiences together.

but started wondering whether it is correct to add an object after "live". Here are some other ways to say what I'm trying to express.

- They went through a lot of of good experiences together.
- They went through a lot of good things together.
- They experienced a lot of good things together?

Comment: Sometimes ***to live*** can be used "transitively". *He lived **the life of Riley**, We live **the good life***, etc. But *semantically*, those highlighted elements are effectively "adverbial" elements modifying the one and only life lived by the subject. You can improve your first sentence just by including a preposition *(They lived **through** a lot of good experiences together)*, but imho ***to live*** isn't really the best verb for the context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for your comment. I have a question: What do you think would by a better verb than "to live" for the context?

Comment: Your own ***went through*** is fine (***experienced*** is a bit "starchy, stilted" to my ear). Also fine (probably the most common phrasing for the context) is [*They **had** a lot of good **times** together*.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22had+a+lot+of+good+times+together%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AJOqlzXpFar0uvApvTjTA8cnSHfHLJmsbQ:1679224064722&source=lnt&tbs=bkv:p&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiV4YCP7ef9AhUyoFwKHcJmDJYQpwV6BAgKEBU&biw=1136&bih=532&dpr=3.33)

Comment: "Lived" on its own doesn't really work here.  "they lived through ..." would work, or even "they had ..."

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is fine, although personally I prefer **went through** rather than **lived.**

Also, you can't really go through "things" (2nd bullet). Instead, you can go through "times":

> They went through a lot of good **times** together.

The other bullets are good.